# Error occured when converting to Json

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on fire base but unfortunately I got an issue that when I put the respUser in console it gave a `[object object]`, then I tried to put `JSON.Stringify` it gave me an Type Error: converting the circular structure to Json then I used `angular.toJson` to convert but it didn't work so please help me,
below is my code..

Thanks in advance

```
 $scope.logIn = function () {

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function (user) {
    console.log(user);

    $scope.populateUserLocally(user); 
      }).catch(function (error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorMessage);
  });};



  $scope.populateUserLocally = function (respUser) {
  $scope.userDetails = angular.toJson(respUser); console.log("$scope.userDetails");    };
```

Comment: You should use `respUser.val()`

Comment: Can you provide your plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use "stringify" for creating JSON string

```
    $scope.userDetails = JSON.stringify(respUser);
```

Comment: i tried JSON.stringify(respUser) but it didnt came.